# Angular 8 replacing tags in dynamically inserted content

Tags: dynamic, output, angular8, html-sanitizing

Is it possible to replace dynamically inserted angular component tags?

I have text like the following which I am getting from an api :

```
Testing <app-test></app-test> for <app-test></app-test> dynamically inserting another <app-test></app-test>
```

I have a test component and all I am trying to achieve is for the output from the text component to replace the `<app-test></app-test>` tags.

In my ts file, I am using DomSanitizer so my tags are not striped out, shown below:

```
this.text = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("Testing <app-test></app-test> for <app-test></app-test> dynamically inserting another <app-test></app-test>");
```

And in my html I am using one-way binding to display the text, like below:

```
<div [innerHTML]='text'></div>
```

But the output is just the text without the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic components by a component ref
In this link you can read about it: https://medium.com/@lukaonik/how-to-create-dynamic-components-in-angular-a2f449acb987

Other solution but not the best is call different components by an ng-swich